# Django fixtures and auto_now_add date time field

Tags: django

Trying to create a fixture for a model with an `auto_now_add` date time field

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

When the fixtures is loaded there is an error thrown `IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture, null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint`

Is there a way to have Django determine the date rather than manually entering a date?

```
[
  {
    "model": "customer.type",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "name": "type",
      "created_by": 1
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the ***easy workaround*** will be using the [**`default`**--[DjangoDoc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#default) and [**`editable`**--[DjangoDoc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#editable) arguments together,

```
from django.utils import timezone


class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
```

The above solution tested and verified under **Django 2.1** and **Python 3.6** environment.

---

#### Drawback of this method

From the [Django-Doc of **`DateField.auto_now_add`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)

> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; **it’s not just a default value that you can override. So even if you set a value for this field when creating the object, it will be ignored.** If you want to be able to modify this field, set the following instead of `auto_now_add=True`

Which means, this setting will override the `timezone.now()` value if you manually provide any valid datetime.